# Mapping new values to a DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with a column called 'quality' that has numeric values between 1 and 9, I want to convert these values as follows:
5 or less gets converted to 0, and 6 or greater gets converted to 1.

this line of code works: 5 gets mapped to 0, and 6 gets mapped to 1.

wine['quality_target'] = wine.quality.map({5:0, 6:1})

However, this line of code throws an error.

wine['quality_target'] = wine.quality.map({<6:0, >5:1})

How do I specify the map, to map (less than 6:0, greater than 5:1

Comment: is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

I would use np.where in this scenario.

```
import numpy as np
df['q'] = np.where(df.Quality < 7, 0, 1))
```

Comment: `df['q']=df.Quality.lt(7).astype(int)`  :-)

Answer (score 0):

In the future you might want to supply some test data and what you've tried. Also formatting your code is also nice. I would try this:

```
import pandas as pd

# some fake data
data = pd.DataFrame({
'col1':[1, 1, 2, 10, 5, 3, 6, 7]
})

map_func = lambda x: 0 if x <= 5 else 1
# apply it to the dataframe
data.col1.apply(map_func)
# this is not done in place so you can create a new column
data['col1_transformed'] = data.col1.apply(map_func)
```